# Filtering and calculating over JSONB object

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-json

I have a table with JSONB column which holds data like this:

```
create table car_stats (
    id int primary key,
    city varchar,
    date timestamp,
    info varchar
    stats jsonb
)
```

stats example:

```
[
  {
    "brand": "AUDI",
    "status": "NEW"
  },
  {
    "brand": "BMW",
    "status": "PRODUCTION"
  },
  {
    "brand": "BMW",
    "status": "NEW"
  },
  {
    "brand": "BMW",
    "status": "NEW"
  },
  {
    "brand": "BMW",
    "status": "DELIVERED"
  }
]
```

I want to count percentage of **new** / **production** / **delivered** of car's brand grouped by city and month

```
 CITY   MONTH BRAND NEW  PRODUCTION DELIVERED
 LONDON  3    AUDI  100%   0          0
 PARIS   2    BMW   50%    25%        25%
```

I tried the following, but I have no idea how to calculate elements in JSON (e.g. all BMW in status NEW)

```
with cte as (
   select stats ->> 'brand',
          stats ->> 'status',
          city, 
          date
   from car_stats
   group by city
), 
 grouped as (
   select cte.brand,
          cte.country,
          cte.date,
          ARRAY_TO_JSON(ARRAY_AGG(base)) as statistics
   from cte
   group by cte.brand, cte.city, cte.date       
 ),
 stats as (
    count % statistics somehow here.. ? 
 )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can associate each each element in `stats` with its corresponding city, and then use `sum` with `group by`:

```
with recursive cte(id, c, p, i, d) as (
   select c.id, c.city, (c.stats ->> 0)::jsonb, 1, c.stats from car_stats c
   union all
   select c.id, c.c, (c.d ->> c.i)::jsonb, c.i+1, c.d from cte c where c.i < jsonb_array_length(c.d)
)
select c.c, extract(month from c1.date), c.p -> 'brand', c.p -> 'factory'
   round(sum(case when (c.p -> 'status')::text = '"NEW"' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*)::decimal,2), 
   round(sum(case when (c.p -> 'status')::text = '"PRODUCTION"' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*)::decimal,2), 
   round(sum(case when (c.p -> 'status')::text = '"DELIVERED"' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*)::decimal,2)
from cte c join car_stats c1 on c.id = c1.id 
group by c.c, extract(month from c1.date), c.p -> 'brand', c -> 'factory'
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7327dcb29a87f39f606a12880b165c68).

Comment: thanks, looks complicated, on big data set that recursive query will be efficient?
and if you could, second thing. If JSONb contains also ex. `"factory" : "germany"`
and I want to group them over this field, to have results like : 
**brand - Audi, factory - Germany  -> arr of JSONs**
and iterate through jsonsb and count only the rate of new / production cars?

Comment: @mmjan See my recent edit, I included `c -> 'factory'` in the grouping parameter. Regarding efficiency, the storage of the car statuses in large JSON strings for each city is violates best normalization practices and inhibits you from leveraging a database's natural ability to perform tasks such as this one up front.

Comment: yeah, good point - could you look on prepared [see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b8479ce7a273f551ed68cadfeb866f67) if my structure looks like this, jsonb with single entry, I had a problem to use yours versions of query, and the last thing, wondering how to do calculation described in comments there.

Answer (score 0):

First expand `brand` and `status` into separate rows using `cross join lateral` and then use `count filter` conditional aggregation.

```sql
with t as 
(
 select city, date_trunc('month', "date")::date y_month, brand, status
 from car_stats 
 cross join lateral
 (
  select j ->> 'brand' brand,
         j ->> 'status' status
  from jsonb_array_elements(stats) j
 ) t
)
select city, y_month, brand,
  count(*) filter (where status = 'NEW')::numeric/count(*)*100 "NEW",
  count(*) filter (where status = 'PRODUCTION')::numeric/count(*)*100 "PRODUCTION",
  count(*) filter (where status = 'DELIVERED')::numeric/count(*)*100 "DELIVERED"
from t
group by city, y_month, brand;
```

Comment: I have a problem when my DB row looks like this: 
`[city: LONDON, date: 2021-02-02, stats: {"brand": "audi", status: "new", "factory": "germany" }]` - received cannot extract elements from an object. 

And wondering how to deal with it and additionally create a query to retrieve data groped by factory and brand...

`factory : germany, brand : audi, stats(arr of jsons) > [{brand: audi, status: new}, {brand: audi, status: new}, {brand: audi, status: production}`

 and then count rate of status: new / status: production per row

Comment: Well, these are very different things. What high level language are you using? "cannot extract elements from an object" is not a PostgreSQL message. As for the second part of your comment - this is exactly what the query in my answer does provided that the DB structure is as shown in the question.

Comment: Running query on pg 12.3, even in dB fiddle created in the answer below if I add JSON with single entry without array like stats: {brand: audi, status: new} same error occurs

Comment: Query is corrected. Added `::numeric` cast. It does work and delivers the expected result.

Comment: well, the query is great, but unfortunately does not work if my 'stats' payload looks like I described in this example [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=114f60bb450cc6ef45029e5413707e97) problem with jsonb_array_elements function occurred

Comment: Pls. see modified fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c62ede89ad54aaee0043d7e06a9aa9e8) or [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7a4ac0cca0bf269dea71bd99f0cb2d41). It works fine and field `car_stats.stats` is a JSON array as your example in the question is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240663/discussion-between-mmjan-and-stefanov-sm).